# Primary Key in DB in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

### guys i was asked to make the design for product table like this

product_code (PK)----------varchar2(5)

product_name---------------varchar2(15)

product_type---------------varchar2(1)

but i want to make an ID auto increment column to be primary key as well to be accessed within any CRUD operations .. can i do this with the existence of primary key product_code ?... or the ID column is useless here ??

Comment: You should make ID as PK, and product code column as unique

Answer (score 2):

Make the `product_id` the primary key as an `auto_increment` column.

You can then define `product_code` as `unique` and `not null`.

Foreign key relationships should use the `product_id` column.

Comment: and the unique not null wouldn't contradict with the requirements ?

Comment: Interesting. Why do you recommend creating FK relationships on the code instead of the ID?

Comment: @JoeStefanelli . . . Ouch!  That was a typo.

Comment: @firstNamelastName . . . `product_code` is currently a primary key.  Hence it is `unique` and `not null`.  If you don't want those characteristics, then remove the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If you've been given requirements that state your primary key should be a varchar2(5) called product_code. I would recommend following the requirements, I see no practical reason to object.

Do you know how many records will exist in this table, do you have reason to believe the requirements provided will introduce an issue? If so document your concerns and ask for clarification, but you appear to be a contractor and I would defer to the customer.

Answer (score 0):

Only the primary key can be auto-generated in MySQL.

Create the table with a new `ID` column that is auto-generated and make your existing `PRODUCT_CODE` column unique, as in:

```
create table product (
  id int primary key not null auto_increment,
  product_code varchar(5) not null,
  product_name varchar(15) not null,
  product_type varchar(1),
  constraint uq_code unique (product_code)
);
```